# Is it fine to use "who" for non-human "parent"?

Tags: nouns, who-whom

I come across this question: [In “h2, h3 a {}”, who is a's parent element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57274188/3416774)

So as "parent" here is not a human, is it fine to use "who" in here?

Comment: I would use 'which'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

‘Who’ is not correct in that situation; it should only be used for people. ‘Which’ is the better word, because  it describes a thing, an ‘it’, rather than a ‘him’, ‘her’, or other pronouns. However, the sentence

> In “h2, h3 a {}”, which is a’s parent element?

is not correct either; you need to identify what you’re talking about with the word ‘which’, so it should be either

> In “h2, h3 a {}”, is h2 or 23 a’s parent element?

Or

> In “h2, h3 a {}”, which element is a’s parent element?

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hmm, when can I use "which is X"? Or is it always in the form "which item/element/etc is X?"

Comment: @Ooker I think it always has to be the second; ‘which’ questions always need an identifier, I think.